# Error when requesting Facebook PHP Api?

Tags: php, facebook

I normally use only the facebook javascript api, but the login started to give me trouble so I'm trying with the PHP api. This is the api call in my header:

```
<?
require 'stuff/facebook-php/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'my app id',
  'secret' => 'secret',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
?>
```

I get these messages on my site:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/02/6945202/html/copoetry/index.php:6) in /home/content/02/6945202/html/copoetry/stuff/facebook-php/src/facebook.php on line 37

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/02/6945202/html/copoetry/index.php:6) in /home/content/02/6945202/html/copoetry/stuff/facebook-php/src/facebook.php on line 37
```

Am I doing something wrong or what could be the issue? Thanks

Comment: mmm. and opening tag should be <?php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent error"

means you've outputted some data on the page and then tried to set headers. Headers must be sent before any html output.

ALSO

> "Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent" comes often when
>   the file is encoded in UTF-8 WITH BOM under Windows. When transfered
>   on an UNIX server the BOM is considered as text and sent before any
>   header you can define.

Make sure to remove any spaces, newlines, or other garbage
before an opening `<?php` tag or after a closing `?>`

Comment: well. whatever you're doing  requires sessions which in turn requires setting cookie which cannot be done after you've outputted anything onto the page.

Comment: Do check that you have correct encoding set for your php files: ANSI or UTF-8 without BOM!

Comment: You could use output buffering to make sure nothing is printed to the page until the script finishes execution

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you didn't output any string (including errors) before starting your session.

Do not use `?>` if you are sure your last line of your file is php code

```
<?php
require 'stuff/facebook-php/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'my app id',
  'secret' => 'secret',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```